# Odoo - Auto close wizard and refresh parent

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I created a normal view for a class in my module. Now i wanted to show that same view in another class on a button click . I have done that but the issue i am facing is that when that popup open it gives two buttons `Save` and `Discard`. Once i click save i should auto close and it should also refresh the parent view from which it was loaded. Is this possible in Odoo?

Beside this how can i create a javascript file in Odoo. I visited official documentation but i was unable to understand that do we have a javascript file against each class or against each module and how to create that and what are the things i can do in that javscript file. Basically i am asking for a well documentation for better understanding.

**Edit** :
This is my button click function

```
@api.multi
def add_deposit_action(self):
    return {
            "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
            "name": 'Add A Deposit',
            "res_model": "amgl.order",
            "views": [[False, "form"]],
            "context": {'customer_id': self.id,
                        'account_number': self.account_number,
                        'date_opened': self.date_opened,
                        'account_type': self.account_type},
            'target': 'new',
            'is_deposit': True
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I visited official documentation but i was unable to understand that do we have a javascript file against each class or against each module and how to create that and what are the things i can do in that javscript file. Basically i am asking for a well documentation for better understanding.

The official documentation of Odoo is here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/. It's quite good to getting to know Odoo and see, how to use the interface. But it could be difficult to find the answer for your technical question there.

Another better way is to create your question inside the forum here: https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1

For me, i have learned a lot from this book: Odoo Development Cookbook. You can try to have a look on this book, if you would like to do more development with Odoo.

---

> I have done that but the issue i am facing is that when that popup open it gives two buttons Save and Discard. Once i click save i should auto close and it should also refresh the parent view from which it was loaded. Is this possible in Odoo?

Yes, it's possible. To reload the parent view (original view), you need to return the tag `reload` in the function, which is called by the button `Save` in your **popup**.

For example:

```py
def function():
   # do something here
   return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.client',
        'tag': 'reload',
   }
```

Comment: and where should i place this code. Because i am already returning `ir.action.window` to show popup and if i add `tag:reload` then popup will not open it will simply refresh page on button click

Comment: in the function of your popup, for the button `Save`

Comment: if i add this tag: reload into above function then even wizard doesn't work

Comment: sorry, it's hard to understand your case. But i didn't mind about the function `add_deposit_action`. I talk about the function in your popup. What is happen under the button `Save`? Did you call a method? So you use this `return` in this method.

Comment: For the question about `well documentation for better understanding` my answer is: NO. Odoo doesn't have any well documentation, and every one know why.

Comment: @qvpham why does Odoo fail to have a well written documentation?

Comment: @BirukAbebe, at the beginning, they have the focus on the community and it was great. Now they have a big community and are focusing more consulting and the partner program. Every business need income to live and this is they way, how they can sell more consulting.